# Intercept Java applet HTTP traffic

Tags: google-chrome-extension, applet

I'm running Chromium 44.0.2403.0 for Windows with [chrome://flags/#enable-npapi](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html).

Is it possible to intercept the HTTP traffic of a Java applet from an extension? I've tried using [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) but it does not seem to be aware of the traffic of said jp2launcher process.

Comment: Does the traffic show up in the Dev Tools' Network pane for the page in question?

Comment: And what do you mean by "intercept"?

Comment: @Xan No, it doesn't show up there. By intercepting I mean reading and potentially modifying the request and response headers and bodies.